# what's the maximum number of nominal values in a nominal attribute for SVM training in WEKA?

Tags: nlp, weka, svm, libsvm

I have an NLP problem and I plan to use classifying in WEKA with SVMs.
I'm trying to classify words - the POS tagset has 24 tags, and the base phrase chunk (BPC) tagset has 15 tags.

But I have "feature sets", and I want each word to be classified for each of its features.

The first feature set is {POS}, so that'll be 24 nominal values for the nominal attribute POS.
The second is {POS+BPC}, so that'll be 24*15=375 nominal values for the POS+BPC nominal attribute.

So for example a word might be output like this, with each nominal attribute classified:

```
word, POS=tag1, POS+BPC=tag234
```

I'm just wondering if this is possible? What's the maximum number of (classes) nominal values I can have for a nominal attribute? Because I might be using more tagsets and more combinations. Would I need to use the LibSVM package? Does it even make sense to do this multi-class problem using SVMs?

My training dataset is approx. 288K words, and my testing dataset is approx. 35k words.

Comment: Your use of the word "class" is highly confusing. You mean nominal *values*; *classes* are the things you're trying to predict.

Answer (score 0):

I know someone who had 3 million features and used weka to build classifiers. But he had to increase the memory provided to weka from 1 GB to 3 GB. Compared to his set up, you have 2 features but a 3 digit value range. I believe there should not be any problem at all other than memory problem. Weka is a large scale mining workbench. Why dont you run a few samples as a sanity test and give us a heads up?